# CSS Grid, grid item "height: 100%" not working in Chrome

Tags: css, css-grid

This is my first post here... so hopefully I get all of the necessary info in this question.

I've been working all day on trying to get the correct grid functionality on some cards I'm creating (see links to screenshots below). After working a while, I was able to get my desired results in Firefox, but when I test in Chrome... It's not anywhere close to the same as Firefox.

Firefox Results

[image: Firefox Results]

Chrome Results

[image: Chrome Results]

It seems when I comment out "height: 100%;" on the image the functionality is *better* in Chrome, but still not what I'm wanting.

Chrome with "height: 100%;" removed:

[image: Chrome with "height: 100%;" removed]

Here's my markup:

```css
.projects {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 7rem;
  &__item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  &__img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    display: block;
    object-position: center;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <div class="projects__item projects__item--1">
    <img src="img/projects-1.png" class="projects__img">
    <div class="projects__content">
      <h3 class="projects__heading--3 heading-3">Project Title</h3>
      <p class="projects__text">
        Insert Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276 (about flex, but applies to grid, as well)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: Does chrome not apply the height that the .projects__item container would have gotten from “grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)” to child elements? I thought that would give it a dynamic height.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So basically what Is happening is there is no height given to the parent container `projects` so when you say `100% height` on the image it doesn't actually know what you mean, height of what??

So to fix it you will need to add a height to your parent container `projects`, now you can set that to be whatever you like but if you want it to be 100% of the screen height you have to use `height: 100vh`

**edit**

On further inspection it looks as if you want all the images to line up the same way as well so what you will have to do is remove your image tag and create a div like so..

```
<div class="img_container">
</div>
```

then in your css

```
.img_container{
    height: 50%; // or whatever value just make sure you give your parent a height
    width: 100%;
    background: url('link to your image') 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 }
```

what this does is creates a container that holds the image and then fits the image to the container so all your images look the same width and height, now you will have to play around with it for a bit but this should give you what you want

Comment: That’s a good solution, thank you @JuvenileSnow! I was really trying to use grid layouts here though... and by using “grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)” on the “&__item” class I thought that would specify a height that would be determined in the browser? Do I need to specify a height there in px or rem for chrome though?

Comment: What I’m also confused about is why it seems to work just fine in Firefox... that’s the most confusing to me.

Comment: After playing around with it, I added a height to the ".projects__item" class, and that seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error , 
I managed to solve it.

```
HTML ERROR ->
<div class="container-grid">
<img src="1.jpg"/>
<img src="2.jpg"/>
<img src="3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The solution

HTML

```
<div class="container-grid">
    <div class="image"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="3.jpg" /></div>
</div>

IN YOUR CSS
.galeria .image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.galeria .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: you just have to put your <img> in a <div> container and the div must have the width: 100% and heidth: 100% as well as <img> .. heidth will not work: 100% unless you configure the grid-template-row and add a dimension